# Can I use dispatch without binding?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have this code:

Action works and data gets returned correctly.

```
import axios from 'axios'

export function getBooks(
    limit = 10,
    start = 0,
    order = 'asc'
) {
    const req = axios.get(`/api/books?limit=${limit}&skip=${start}&order=${order}`)
                .then(res => res.data);

    return {
        type: 'GET_BOOKS',
        payload: req
    }

}
```

In the next file `this.props` is empty

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { getBooks } from '../actions'


class HomeContainer extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.props.dispatch(getBooks(3, 0, 'desc'));
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props);    
        return (
            <div>
                Home Items
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        book_reducer: state.book_reducer
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HomeContainer)
```

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import promiseMiddleware from 'redux-promise';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';

import reducers from './reducers';
import Routes from './routes';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(promiseMiddleware, ReduxThunk)(createStore);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes/>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
    , document.getElementById('root'));
```

book_reducer.js

```
export default function(state = {}, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'Get_BOOKS':
            return {...state, list:action.payload}
        default: return state;
    }
}
```

Any idea why this does not work?

Comment: dont dispatch from the constructor, dispatch from `componentDidMount`, that would be the more correct way to do it. You could just reference the `props` you have (aka remove `this` and just call `props.dispatch(...)`)

Comment: you aren't using `async`/`await` for the request, are you sure the data is getting returned correctly?

Comment: still empty `book_reducer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you made a typo in the reducer

```
case 'Get_BOOKS':
```

it should be

case 'GET_BOOKS': this is what you return from the function

Comment: already using `redux-thunk` but `props.book_reducer` is empty

Comment: if console.log(req)  returns something, everything looks like fine here. You need to share your reducers. btw did you add index.js after my answer or I was blind that i couldnt see redux-thunk

Comment: console.log(req) return the data. I added index after your answer. reducer code added.

Comment: book_reducer.js you shared the getBooks function instead

Comment: you just made a typo in the reducer: case 'Get_BOOKS': GET_BOOKS

Comment: This is why you should make these a constant variable that you reference in each place. So you avoid simple errors like a typo